# Angular Coefficient (b) in R

Tags: r

How do I get the coefficient of a regression in R? In the equation of the Regression line, where `y = a + bx`, the Angular coefficient would be the `"b"`. I would also like to know how to calculate the intercept - the `"a"` of the equation

Comment: please use English

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not in English - this is an **English-only** site - please respect the rules of the site!

Comment: Ok! Sorry! What would I know is to estimate the b and a from the linear regression model y = a + bx in R. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I only speak enough spanish to understand a little bit, try:

```
Model <- lm(y ~ 1 + x) 
summary(Model)$coefficients
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it!